# Why isn't my ArrayList adding an object?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am new to coding, and I am not quite sure why this error is occurring. I am getting a "java.lang.NullPointerException" when I try to add an object to my ArrayList.

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ShoppingCart3
{
    private int itemCount;
    private double totalPrice;
    private ArrayList<Item> cart;

    public ShoppingCart3()
    {
         itemCount = 0;
         totalPrice = 0.0;
         ArrayList<Item> cart = new ArrayList<Item>();
         cart = new ArrayList<Item>();
    }

    public void addToCart(String itemName, double price, int quantity)
    {
        Item x = new Item(itemName, price, quantity);
        cart.add(x); **<-----Error Happens Here**
        totalPrice += (price * quantity);
    }
```

There is more code after, but I don't think it is a problem. Thank you so much for your help, and sorry if it a really silly error that I cannot see. :P

Comment: Why do you declare a local `cart` variable in your constructor? You already have one as a field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are re-declaring a `cart` variable in the constructor, so you are initializing a local `List`, while your `cart` member remains null.

Change

```
 public ShoppingCart3()
 {
      itemCount = 0;
      totalPrice = 0.0;
      ArrayList<Item> cart = new ArrayList<Item>();
      cart = new ArrayList<Item>();
 }
```

to

```
 public ShoppingCart3()
 {
      itemCount = 0;
      totalPrice = 0.0;
      cart = new ArrayList<Item>();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor, in this line:

```
ArrayList<Item> cart = new ArrayList<Item>();
cart = new ArrayList<Item>();
```

you are *not* initializing the member variable `cart` of the class, you are declaring a new, local variable that hides the member variable. The member variable stays `null`, so that when you call `add` on it in `addToCart`, you get a `NullPointerException`.

In the second line, you are just re-initializing the local variable again. The member variable still stays `null`.

Do this instead to initialize the member variable:

```
cart = new ArrayList<Item>();
```

Remove the line in which you declare and initialize the local variable.

Answer (score 1):

You redefine yor list here:

```
public ShoppingCart3()
 {
      itemCount = 0;
      totalPrice = 0.0;
      ArrayList<Item> cart = new ArrayList<Item>(); //  redefine
      cart = new ArrayList<Item>(); // initialieze redefined list
 }
```

Try:

```
public ShoppingCart3()
 {
      itemCount = 0;
      totalPrice = 0.0;
     // ArrayList<Item> cart = new ArrayList<Item>(); //  redefine
      cart = new ArrayList<Item>(); 
 }
```

or

```
public ShoppingCart3()
 {
      itemCount = 0;
      totalPrice = 0.0;
      ArrayList<Item> cart = new ArrayList<Item>(); //  redefine
      this.cart = new ArrayList<Item>(); // initialieze list from instance
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

you declared two variables

```
  private ArrayList<Item> cart;
```

one is local and you initiate local variable not class global

```
  ArrayList<Item> cart = new ArrayList<Item>();
  cart = new ArrayList<Item>();
```

Problem is :

```
public class ShoppingCart3
{
 private int itemCount;
 private double totalPrice;
 private ArrayList<Item> cart;      // Global for your class 

 public ShoppingCart3()
 {
      itemCount = 0;
      totalPrice = 0.0;
      ArrayList<Item> cart = new ArrayList<Item>();  // local in constructor 
      cart = new ArrayList<Item>();                  // you initiate this 
 }
```

`ArrayList<Item> cart = new ArrayList<Item>();  // local in constructor`  remove this line

Answer (score 0):

local variable `cart` of the constructor hides the field. Therefore your `cart` field is not initialized